# How to modify the language of the application

Tags: macos

I use Mac 10.8.2 operating systems, there are a lot of applications, my system language is English, may I ask how to modify the application of the language (not the operating system), for example, to change the Japanese, is not there a configuration canmodify?For example: Info.plist class

Answer (score 0):

It will vary from application to application, depending on how each supports (or doesn't) other languages from the default.

However, for many apps, the methods from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/42791/can-i-change-the-default-language-of-a-application-program-in-snow-leopard) seem promising.

Answer (score 0):

The app will use whatever language it supports, and this is selected within the operating system (from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000278-SW1)):

> In iOS, the user designates a preferred language by navigating to
>   General > International > Language in the Settings application.
>   Because iOS-based devices support only one user, only one language at
>   a time is selected. In OS X, the Language & Text system preference
>   panel lets the user designate both a preferred language and one or
>   more fallback languages in case the preferred language is unavailable.